# Invalid date being returned

Tags: javascript, mirth

using Mirth Connect.

I'm trying to get the current date and add 2 days to it.

it is currently 8:10am Eastern Time 3/24/2016

```
var startDate
var currentDay = DateUtil.getCurrentDate('F');
var currentDate = new Date(DateUtil.getCurrentDate('yyyy-MM-dd'));

logger.info("Current: " + currentDate);
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+2);
startDate = DateUtil.formatDate('yyyy-MM-dd', currentDate);
logger.info("+2: " + startDate);
```

I get this in return

`[2016-03-24 08:10:09,694]  INFO  (db-connector:?): Current: Wed Mar 23 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` - It's not wednesday nor is the time correct

`[2016-03-24 08:10:09,694]  INFO  (db-connector:?): +2: 2016-03-25`
 - This should display Saturdays 2016-03-26 since i'm adding +2 days to the current time.

`var currentDay = DateUtil.getCurrentDate('F');` however returns 4 so it is thursday.

Comment: What's `DateUtil`?

Comment: it's the library built into Mirth

Comment: Using jsfiddle I wasn't able to reproduce your issue... can you make this available somewhere for test?

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to the following which solved my issue.

```
var currentDTTM = new java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
currentDTTM.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, 2);
var strCurrentDTTM = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(currentDTTM.getTime());
```